# PostGIS st_point functoin returns null values for all records that do not meet criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create geom values for new records coming from field devices that have latitude and longitude value in two fields (latitude, longitude), for a given project using the following expression:

```
UPDATE public.data_mds_import

SET geom=(

SELECT 

    st_force3d(st_setsrid(st_point(public.data_mds_import.longitude, public.data_mds_import.latitude),4326))

WHERE PUBLIC.data_mds_import.id_jobcode=220 /* ENTER ID_JOBCODE HERE */

    );
```

We have lots of field data coming in and i need a statement where i can just change the jobcode value in the statement for each new set of field data that gets imported.

The problem is that for other jobs in the table where jobcode != 220, the function returns null values, i.e. it removes the geom value, i lose my geometry data so i go from having several thousand records with a geometry value before the function runs, to only the records where jobcode = '220'.

Why is this happening, the statement should be selecting only records where jobcode=220 right? Whereas it appears to select all records and return the geometry where jobcode = 220, and null for every other record. No action would be better than null.

Should i use a case statement? If so can someone please help with such a statement, i have tried several case statement variations and cant get a statement to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

If you're updating a single table, there is no need to use a suquery to simply update a column. Also, you don't need to repeat the schema and table names.

This query selects all records that correspond to `id_jobcode = 220` and creates a geometry in the column `geom` from the values of `latitude` and `logitude`:

```
UPDATE public.data_mds_import
SET geom = ST_Force3D(
             ST_SetSRID(
               ST_Point(longitude, latitude),4326))
WHERE id_jobcode = 220;
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the reply. 
So the only difference between your code and mine is that i inadvertently used a subquery? Would this in itself result in the problem described? i.e. the 'Set' function returns a geometry for the subquery (id_jobcode =200) record set and thus Null for all other records? Shouldnt the subquery itself rule out all jobcodes that != 220

Whatever the case i tested it and it works, so simple, silly error, thank you very much.